# Error "One of the parameters supplied is invalid (0x100003e80)" on VMware Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion

This issue has been plaguing me for months! Whenever I try to extend the size the hard disk of a virtual machine (Windows 7 Guest on MacOS Host) I get the following error:

`One of the parameters supplied is invalid (0x100003e80)`

I've tried:

- Reinstalling VMware Fusion
- Upgrading to VMware Fusion v11.1
- Changing the Bus type
- Using the following command in terminal"

`"/applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager" -x 120Gb "/Users/me/VMs/Windows 7 x64.vmwarevm/Virtual Disk.vmdk"`

All to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

VMware KB suggests a fix for another VMWare hard disk issue which seems to also fix the resizing issue I've been having.

- Shutdown and VM and quit VMware Fusion
- Open up the .vmwarevm package
- Back up a `Virtual Disk.vmdk`
- Open `Virtual Disk.vmdk` in an editor
- Toward the bottom, there was a line `ddb.adapterType = "“ide”"`
- I Replaced it with `ddb.adapterType = "lsilogic"`

That seemed to do the trick, hard disk expansion went off without a hitch.